# The mongodb connection throw MongoSocketReadException

Tags: java, mongodb, haproxy

All, I have encountered a strange issue.

I have 3 MongoDB servers and have combined them into a `replset`--one is primary and the other 2 are secondary nodes.
My MongoDB client is a Java MongoDB client, Spring environment.

And I use `haproxy` to direct to the `replset` node.

Sometimes when I connect to the `haproxy`, the mongo client will throw the following exception:

`message:Exception found: Prematurely reached end of stream; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream`

When I retry, it will disappear, and after some minutes it will appear again.

My `haproxy` config is show below:

```
global
  daemon
  user vcap
  group vcap
  log /dev/log daemon info
  maxconn 4096

defaults
  log global
  option dontlognull
  mode  tcp
  timeout connect  5000ms
  timeout client  30000ms
  timeout server  30000ms
  retries   3
  option redispatch

# admin gui
listen stats
bind :8080
mode http
stats enable
stats uri /stats

default-server  on-error fastinter error-limit 3 inter 3000ms fastinter 1000ms downinter 300s fall 3

frontend fe_mongo_27027_tcp
  bind 0.0.0.0:27027
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  use_backend be_mongo_27027_tcp

backend be_mongo_27027_tcp
  mode tcp
  option tcp-check
  # mongodb wire protocol
  tcp-check send-binary 3a000000 # Message Length (58)
  tcp-check send-binary EEEEEEEE # Request ID (random value)
  tcp-check send-binary 00000000 # Response To (nothing)
  tcp-check send-binary d4070000 # OpCode (Query)
  tcp-check send-binary 00000000 # Query Flags
  tcp-check send-binary 61646d696e2e # fullCollectionName (admin.$cmd)
  tcp-check send-binary 24636d6400 # continued
  tcp-check send-binary 00000000 # NumToSkip
  tcp-check send-binary FFFFFFFF # NumToReturn
  # Start of Document
  tcp-check send-binary 13000000 # Document Length (19)
  tcp-check send-binary 10 # Type (Int32)
  tcp-check send-binary 69736d617374657200 # ismaster:
  tcp-check send-binary 01000000 # Value : 1
  tcp-check send-binary 00 # Term

  tcp-check expect binary 69736d61737465720001 #ismaster True
  # mongodb check end

  option tcplog
  option tcpka

  server mongodb-10.62.90.175 10.62.90.175:27017 check inter 2000

  server mongodb-10.62.90.176 10.62.90.176:27017 check inter 2000

  server mongodb-10.62.90.174 10.62.90.174:27017 check inter 2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is due to timeout setting, the connection is close so the mongo client can't receive the binary, now i remove the timeout setting and it works now.